# How to use RCTConvert NSArray

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I'm trying to convert a JSON string to native objectiveC objects using the RCTConvert class and it fails for a reason I can't understand.

The string I receive:

```
["CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=xxx; path=/; domain=zzzz; secure; HttpOnly; ","CloudFront-Signature=yyy; path=/; domain=aaa; secure; HttpOnly; ","CloudFront-Policy=bbb; path=/; domain=ccc; secure; HttpOnly; "]
```

I'm calling `[RCTConvert NSArray: passedCookiesString]` and getting the error that `JSON value '<string above>' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSArray`

Clearly i'm missing something as to how this method is to be used...

Comment: Should it not be `[RCTConvert NSString:passedCookiesString]` ?

Comment: and what you receive is a string or array or json?

Comment: @OlSen my understanding is that `[RCTConvert NSString:passedCookiesString]` will try to convert passedCookiesString into a string. Which it already is and thus return the same value. passedCookiesString is an NSString which contains the string i put in the post above

Comment: then i would read https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTConvert.m and use `RCT_DEBUG` to find out whats wrong

Comment: Thanks @OlSen, I already did that unfortunately and could not figure out what was wrong.